# I'm trying to send multiple checkboxes through angular form builder but its not working

Tags: angular, forms, formbuilder

**when i'm running this code the checkboxes are not visible on the frontend. what I'm trying to do is taking multiple inputs of checkboxes from user and and sending it to an api. Please assist for this.**

```
 <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit(form.value)">
        <div *ngFor="let addon of addOns; let i = index">
                <input type="checkbox" [formControl] ="addOn">
                {{user.addOns[i].name}}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">
                Calculate Premium
        </button>
    </form>
    {{ form.value | json }}
```

this is the component class the data is not binding with form control name - do anyone can tell me what is wrong im doing in this

```
     export class FourWheelerComponent implements OnInit {

  user ={
    addOns:[
      {name:'IsValidDrivingLicense', selected:true, id:1},
      {name:'IsMoreThanOneVehicle', selected:false, id:2},
      {name:'IsNoPrevInsurance', selected:false, id:3},
      {name:'IsTransferOfNCB', selected:false, id:4}
    ]
  }
  form;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
  private _quoteService: QuoteService) { 
    console.clear();

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      addOns:this.buildAddOns()
    });
    console.log(this.form.get("addOns"))
  }



  ngOnInit() {


  }
  getAddOns(): FormArray{
    return this.form.get('addOns') as FormArray;
  };

  buildAddOns(){
    const arr = this.user.addOns.map(s=>{
      return this.fb.control(s.selected,);
    })
    return this.fb.array(arr);
  }


  submit(value){
    const f = Object.assign({}, value, {
      addOns: value.addOns.map((s,i) =>{
        return{
          name: this.user.addOns[i].name,
          selected:s,

        }
      })
    });
    console.log(f);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is in the get function which you have written `getAddOns()` which should be `get addOns()` as it is the getter function,which is being used when we are creating form group, on this line `addOns:this.buildAddOns()` i have tried the code just to check ,
 which is on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-checkbox you can look into it.